# How to use custom column that include ready

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubectl

Hi I am trying to run kubectl -n*** get pods

this return the standard one and it includes names, ready, and status...

What I need is the name and ready
However, I couldn't do this by using custom-column.
Need helps on how I can add the ready column back to the custom-column

kubectl -n*** get pods -o=custom-columns="NAME:.metadata.name"

Thanks in advance

Comment: The value for the "READY" column is not taken from the pod itself but rather calculated on the fly, you wouldn't be able to use custom-columns's json-path expression for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl get pods -o custom-columns='NAME:metadata.name,READY:status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `go-template`:

```
 kubectl  get pods -o go-template='{{range $index, $element := .items}}{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{if .ready }}{{$element.metadata.name}}  {{"READY\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

Example:

```
k get pod
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
httpd-757fb56c8d-2vnw4   1/1     Running   2 (6h24m ago)   3d3h
readiness-exec            0/1     Running   0               22s #<---this is not ready
nginx                    1/1     Running   2 (6h24m ago)   4d1h
nginx-6799fc88d8-5cflk   1/1     Running   2 (6h24m ago)   3d3h
```

// non-ready(`readiness-exec`) pod is not listed:

```
kubectl  get pods -o go-template='{{range $index, $element := .items}}{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{if .ready }}{{$element.metadata.name}}  {{"READY\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
httpd-757fb56c8d-2vnw4  READY
nginx  READY
nginx-6799fc88d8-5cflk  READY
```

//once the `readiness-exec` pod is ready:

```
kubectl  get pods -o go-template='{{range $index, $element := .items}}{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{if .ready }}{{$element.metadata.name}}  {{"READY\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}' |column -t
httpd-757fb56c8d-2vnw4   READY
readiness-exec           READY
nginx                    READY
nginx-6799fc88d8-5cflk   READY
```